# Typescript is not removed even after reinstalling node

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

While working on Angular 5 project, I got the following error on compilation :

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 2.7.2 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

    npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
```

To fix this error did the following:

1. Deleted all node_module instances, and uninstalled node from control panel -> add/remove programs.
2. Reinstalled node
3. Checked in cmd:npm view typescript version
4. I received version as 3.2.2
5. npm uninstall -g typescript
6. npm cache verify

Still typescript is not removed from npm. 
Can some one help me uninstall typescript completely? Been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: You need to clear the npm cache `C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: what about package.json? does it contain the typescript reference?

Comment: @sachinGupta: npm cache folder is empty as its a fresh install

Comment: @ChristianMüller: Tried outside my project folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a small mistake in compiler log:
Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

```
npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0'
```

should be

```
npm install typescript@">=2.4.2 <2.7.0"
```

Comment: The single quote works in bash, not in windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a mismatch in your package json. Update the typescript version as suggested and update package.json

run: 
    `npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' --save`

Comment: Even after running outside my project path and uninstalling globally, I still get typescript version.

Comment: Did you try updating the angular cli ?

Comment: Thanks! finally able to fix this one, the only issue was to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the command npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' --save. 
Following is the proper command for any one stuck :

npm install typescript@">=2.4.2 <2.7.0" --save

Answer (score 0):

Check following step:

- You call `@angular/compiler-cli` in global or local(just one folder), you need install `typescript` same.
- Install `typescript` match `'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0'`, example : `typescript@2.6.2`, local or global with `-g`.
- Try close your `cmd`, reopen it (if typescript install global, cmd don't know it change if you don't reopen).
- Check your eviroment variable `NODE_PATH`, if it exist, go to that folder to remove module in that.

To check `NODE_PATH`, type in your cmd : `echo %NODE_PATH%`